# Issue with Threading in Java Swing - GUI Thread not Working as Expected

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Java console-based application that manages products. I'm trying to integrate a Swing-based GUI into this application. The goal is to have the GUI operate independently through threading while the console application continues its functionality. However, the GUI thread doesn't seem to start or function as expected.

WestministerShoppingManager.java

```
package cli;

import gui.GUIThread;
import gui.LoginGUI;
import main.Clothing;
import main.Electronics;
import main.Product;
import main.ShoppingManager;
import utils.DBConnection;
import utils.InputValidator; //custom defined input validators

import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WestminsterShoppingManager implements ShoppingManager {

    private final ArrayList<Product> products;
    private ArrayList<Product> deletedProducts;
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final InputValidator inputValidator = new InputValidator();

    public WestminsterShoppingManager() {
        products = new ArrayList<>();
        deletedProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        loadProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public synchronized void displayMenu() {
        String choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("\nMenu:");
            System.out.println("1. Add a new product");
            System.out.println("2. Delete a product");
            System.out.println("3. Print list of products");
            System.out.println("4. Save products to file");
            System.out.println("5. Open customer login(GUI)");
            System.out.println("6. Exit");

            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            choice = scanner.next();

            switch (choice) {
                case "1" -> addProduct();
                case "2" -> deleteProduct();
                case "3" -> printProducts();
                case "4" -> saveProducts();
                case "5" ->{
                    GUIThread guiThread=new GUIThread();
                    guiThread.start();
                }
                case "6" -> System.out.println("Exit the program...");
                default -> System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }
        } while (!choice.equals("5"));

    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct() {

        System.out.println("Add Product");

        if (products.size() > 50) {
            System.out.println("Maximum product limit reached (50 products). Cannot add more.");
            return;  // for exit method
        }

        System.out.print("Product ID: ");
        String productId = scanner.next();
        if (isExistProductID(productId)) {
            System.out.println("Already Existing product id");
            return;
        }

        System.out.print("Product Name: ");
        String productName = scanner.next();

        int availableItems = inputValidator.get_int("Available Items: ");

        double price = inputValidator.get_double("Price: ");

        System.out.println("1. Electronics");
        System.out.println("2. Clothing");
        System.out.print("Select product type to add:");
        String choice = scanner.next();

        switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                System.out.print("Brand: ");
                String brand = scanner.next();

                int warrantyPeriod = inputValidator.get_int("Warranty Period (Months): ");

                Electronics newElectronics = new Electronics(productId, productName, availableItems, price, brand, warrantyPeriod);
                products.add(newElectronics);
                System.out.println("Electronics added successfully");
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.print("Size: ");
                String size = scanner.next();

                System.out.print("Color: ");
                String color = scanner.next();

                Clothing newClothing = new Clothing(productId, productName, availableItems, price, size, color);
                products.add(newClothing);
                System.out.println("Clothing added successfully");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid Choice");
        }
    }

    private boolean isExistProductID(String productID) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            return product.getProductID().equals(productID);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct() {
        if (products.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No products available for delete.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Delete Product");

        System.out.print("Product Id:");
        String deleteProductId = scanner.next().strip();

        Product deletedProduct = null;
        for (Product product : products) {
            if (product.getProductID().equals(deleteProductId)) {
                deletedProduct = product;
                System.out.println("Product Delete ");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (deletedProduct == null) {
            System.out.println("Product with ID " + deleteProductId + " not found.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Deleted Product");
        System.out.println(deletedProduct);

        System.out.print("Are you sure to delete this product(Y/n)?");
        String yN = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
        if (yN.equals("y")) {
            products.remove(deletedProduct);
            deletedProducts.add(deletedProduct);
            System.out.println("Product delete successfully");
            System.out.println(deletedProduct.getAvailableItems() + " left the system");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printProducts() {
        Collections.sort(products);
        for (Product product : products) {
            System.out.println(product + "\n");
        }
    }

    public void saveProducts() {
        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            String sql;
            PreparedStatement statement = null;
            for (Product product : products) {

                if (product instanceof Electronics) {
                    sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Electronics (productID, productName, availableItems, price, brand, warrantyPeriod) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)";
                    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    statement.setString(5, ((Electronics) product).getBrand());
                    statement.setInt(6, ((Electronics) product).getWarrantyPeriod());
                } else if (product instanceof Clothing) {
                    sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Clothing (productID, productName, availableItems, price, size, color) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    statement.setString(5, ((Clothing) product).getSize());
                    statement.setString(6, ((Clothing) product).getColor());
                }
                assert statement != null;
                statement.setString(1, product.getProductID());
                statement.setString(2, product.getProductName());
                statement.setInt(3, product.getAvailableItems());
                statement.setDouble(4, product.getPrice());
                statement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // if delete products delete form the db
            deleteProductsDB(connection);

            System.out.println("Data save to database");
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadProducts() {
        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            loadElectronics(connection);
            loadClothing(connection);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void loadElectronics(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String electronicSQL = "SELECT productID, productName, availableItems, price, brand, warrantyPeriod FROM Electronics";

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(electronicSQL);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String productId = resultSet.getString("productID");
            String productName = resultSet.getString("productName");
            int availableItems = resultSet.getInt("availableItems");
            double price = resultSet.getDouble("price");
            String brand = resultSet.getString("brand");
            int warrantyPeriod = resultSet.getInt("warrantyPeriod");

            products.add(new Electronics(productId, productName, availableItems, price, brand, warrantyPeriod));
        }
    }

    private void loadClothing(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String clothingSQL = "SELECT productID, productName, availableItems, price, size, color FROM Clothing";

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(clothingSQL);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String productId = resultSet.getString("productID");
            String productName = resultSet.getString("productName");
            int availableItems = resultSet.getInt("availableItems");
            double price = resultSet.getDouble("price");
            String size = resultSet.getString("size");
            String color = resultSet.getString("color");
            products.add(new Clothing(productId, productName, availableItems, price, size, color));
        }
    }

    private void deleteProductsDB(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql;
        for (Product product : deletedProducts) {
            sql = "DELETE FROM ";
            sql += product instanceof Electronics ? "Electronics WHERE productId=?" : "Clothing WHERE productId=?";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, product.getProductID());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        deletedProducts.clear();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WestminsterShoppingManager().displayMenu();
    }
}
```

GUIThread.java

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            LoginGUI gui = new LoginGUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Issue Encountered:

When I trigger the GUI thread from the console application, it seems to execute the GUI operations on the main thread, causing the program to operate sequentially rather than asynchronously. I've attempted various threading approaches but haven't achieved the expected behavior.

I expect the GUI to run independently using a separate thread while the console-based operations continue to function.

Comment: How do you know that it's not creating a new thread?

Comment: console not working after start GUI

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me initially you planned to have only 5 menus and added 6th menu later. While this was added to your menu, it was not updated in your switch inside `displayMenu` method.

You should change below

```
while (!choice.equals("5"));
```

to

```
while (!choice.equals("6"));
```

Notice **5** is changed to **6**.

Comment: You should mark answer correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You exit the loop when the user presses 5 to open the GUI:

```
public synchronized void displayMenu() {
    String choice;
    do {
        /* ... */

        switch (choice) {
            case "1" -> addProduct();
            case "2" -> deleteProduct();
            case "3" -> printProducts();
            case "4" -> saveProducts();
            case "5" ->{
                GUIThread guiThread=new GUIThread();
                guiThread.start();
            }
            case "6" -> System.out.println("Exit the program...");
            default -> System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }
    } while (!choice.equals("5")); // here

}
```

Fixing this requires replacing `while (!choice.equals("5"))` with while `(!choice.equals("6"))`